# Is it possible to define permissions on specific resource attributes with cancan 1.6.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, cancan, rails-admin

In CanCan version  1.6.5

Is it possible to define permissions on specific resource attributes ?

For example, if I want to allow a user to only update the name and priority of a project, pass that as the third argument to can.

```
can :update, :projects, [:name, :priority]
```

I want this functionality with rails-admin.

Answer (score 0):

There is special `Active Controller` plugin called `Strong Parameters`.

> With this plugin Action Controller parameters are forbidden to be used
>   in Active Model mass assignments until they have been whitelisted.
>   This means you'll have to make a conscious choice about which
>   attributes to allow for mass updating and thus prevent accidentally
>   exposing that which shouldn't be exposed

`Cancan` not the best way to filter & check params, [read about it](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/issues/571).

There is closed issue in `rails_admin` project, [read about it](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/issues/1347).